# Optimize multiple asynchronous function call

Tags: javascript, performance, async-await

Given those two pieces of code :

```
async function waitAll() {
    await call1();
    await call2();
    await call3();
}
```

And

```
function callPromises() {
    Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(/* .... */)
}
```

What is the most optimized way to call all my async methods ?
My opinion is that `Promise.all` in this situation is faster but I cannot find any answer treating about it.

Of course I am open to any solution that would be better than the two I provided.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the calls are not dependent on each other:

```
async function callPromises() {
  await Promise.all([call1(), call2(), call3()]);
}
```

Comment: Why ? Could you provide more details to your answer if possible ?

Comment: From my understanding, doing linear awaits like the first example will cause them to fire off only after all prior have resolved. Using promise.all or promise.allSettled will cause all the promises to begin and resolve independently. Hence more performant.

Comment: @A.Vinuela calling them sequentially using `async/await` is preferred if order matters. If not, using `Promise.all` is considered more performant. Does that answer your question?